# Critical Reading in the New SAT Question

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The following is an exercise from Erica Meltzer's book *The Critical Reader, the Complete Guide to SAT Critical Reading*:

> They tell us that the eight-hour movement cannot be enforced, for the reason that it must check industrial and commercial progress.
>
> *Check* most nearly means:
>
> a) ensure
> b) restrict
> c) control
> d) observe

I was sure the answer was A, but the answer provided is B. How on earth is it B? "The eight-hour movement cannot be enforced for the reason that is must restrict industrial and commercial progress?"

That makes no sense. It was the first answer choice I eliminated!

Comment: *The eight-hour movement cannot be enforced, for the reason that if it were enforced, it would restrict industrial and commercial progress.* This sentence was written in 1890, and it uses somewhat archaic English. I don't think anybody would use that wording today.

Comment: Is there a reason for why I can eliminate answer choice A? I understand how the sentence could be interpreted in the way you wrote it, but I still see my original interpretation to be equally valid...

Comment: Without knowing the context the above is meaningless.  I would *guess* that it's referring to the movement to implement the 8-hour work day, but even with that assumption the wording is archaic and hard to decipher.  (I can't understand why this would be in a SAT.)

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks! That's what I was looking for! A clear way to know exactly why answer A must be eliminated.

Comment: Google "to keep in check".

Comment: You can eliminate answer A because *"check"* doesn't mean *"ensure"*. It can mean *"observe"*, but that doesn't make any sense in the sentence.

Comment: I agree this sentence is a little weird, but I do think that knowing this meaning of *check* will be a nice ace up your sleeve going into an SAT.

Comment: Dictionaries are useful... See the transitive verb definitions. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check

Comment: Agree with @aparente001. *Check* in this context means restrict or arrest. It's all about the meaning of *check*.